# What is the best way to store grid locations in the database?

Tags: performance, database-design, gridster

I have a grid derived from http://gridster.net/.

- Columns of the grid are seen as different Type[s] of entity.
- Rows are seen as Priority.

[image: Grid example]

Each cell is an object like this

**Entity**

- Id
- Name
- Priority
- TypeId

Note: Priority and TypeId are both Ints are actually relate to Grid/Column location when generating this grid.

**My problem:**
Every time cell is moved around I need to update TypeId and Priority of that cell as well as detect any other cells that might have moved around.

Normally that means mass update on all cells below to priority + 1 (since it has moved down).

This solution obviously works, but I would like to decouple this design and actually maybe another table in the database that would be responsible for keep track of the priority. (it doesn't need to be strongly related to grid id, but it should be able to do something like Order By Priority) with some sort of other table that would be responsible for order/priority. Especially if I were to have another grid and only show entity some entities.

I thought that approach of Linked list could be good. Where I keep track of whats above and what is below, (Previous & Next) however this would be very difficult to run queries on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had nearly the exact same question.

The big difference for me was not how to store the data but the best way to send the modified data.

Instantiate gridster and add a drop event

```
$(".gridster ul").gridster({
        draggable: {
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                window.setTimeout(SavePositions, 200); //short timeout to allow DOM to update
            }
        }
    });
```

So your default gridster looks roughly like this:

```
<div class="gridster ready">
      <ul style="height: 480px; position: relative;">
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w"></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w"></li>

        <li data-row="3" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w"></li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2" class="gs_w"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Detecting changes can be problematic so I send all the data for all grid elements in case any moved unintentionally.

```
function SavePositions() {
    var gridElements = [];
    $(".gridster > ul > .gs_w").each(function() {
        gridElements.push({ 
            Id: $(this).data("id"), 
            Priority: $(this).data("row"), 
            TypeId: $(this).data("col") 
        });
    });

    var data = { Gadgets: gridElements };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<whatever>",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Once in your application, you can manipulate and store these however you like.
I personally used MongoDB which allowed me to, as you say, perform filtering and ordering on the data. While this doesn't decouple the design, it was a clean and dynamic solution.
When stored using MongoDB, it looked something like this:

```
{
    Id: "83cd82f7-d024-4994-9f8d-0595472398e6",
    Gadgets: [
        {
            Id: "8592c6b7-2b39-4b5c-ac08-0666b9fd6152",
            Priority: 1, 
            TypeId: 1
        },
        {
            Id: "8592c6b7-2b39-4b5c-ac08-0666b9fd6152",
            Priority: 1, 
            TypeId: 2
        },
        {
            Id: "8592c6b7-2b39-4b5c-ac08-0666b9fd6152",
            Priority: 1, 
            TypeId: 3
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to apply a filter or order, you'll need a method of rearranging the items rows and columns. The biggest problem I faced was adding, ordering or removing from the grid and having the other items change their positions. I would avoid usage of linked lists in your case too, while you may be able to visualize the columns as linked lists, the grid elements can interact with other columns and that is important to be able to represent/capture.

For example:
In your image, if you filtered out all items with priority of "1", you would leave large gaps at the top of your page before your first elements since your rows and columns are saved to a database.

My approach to that problem involved a 2-dimensional array as a representation of locations and sizes.

I hope I've been slightly helpful?